# Windows Key on Lenovo T520 not launching keyboard shortcut menu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, shortcut-keys, lenovo

I am running 18.04 in my laptop and I see all over the internet that pressing and hold the <kbd>Windows</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> key will bring up the list of all shortcuts in a nice menu window but that does not happen on my Lenovo T520 laptop. If I press and hold nothing happens.. if I press and release it brings up all open applications.

What am I doing wrong?

-DK